# SAP BMBC Transaction - Detail Function is disabled and cannot switch between Batch Master and Usage

Tags: sap-erp

Why is it I cannot switch detail functions (Batch Master<->Usage) in BMBC Transaction? Details function is disabled by default and does not enable even if I already selected a batch. Any other configuration needed?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See SAP Note:
2365492 - BIC: Detail button in the batch information cockpit is disabled